# replicate rows by n times in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that the first column are strings, the 2nd column are the numbers that I want to replicate each string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'String':['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        'Times':[2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5]})
df
```

| String | Times |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 5 |
| d | 3 |
| e | 2 |
| f | 4 |
| g | 5 |

How can I create a data frame into this in python? (stopped at d but you know the pattern). Thanks!

| String | Times |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| c | 4 |
| c | 5 |

Comment: Related: [How can I replicate rows in Pandas?](/q/50788508/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method could be:

```
df.assign(Times = df.Times.apply(lambda x: range(1, x + 1))).explode('Times')
Out[]: 
  String Times
0      a     1
0      a     2
1      b     1
1      b     2
1      b     3
2      c     1
2      c     2
2      c     3
2      c     4
2      c     5
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit messy, but seems to do what you want:

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.String.str.repeat(df.Times).apply(list).explode().reset_index(drop=True))

new_df["Times"] = new_df.groupby("String").cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```py
   String  Times
0       a      1
1       a      2
2       b      1
3       b      2
4       b      3
5       c      1
6       c      2
7       c      3
8       c      4
9       c      5
10      d      1
11      d      2
12      d      3
13      e      1
14      e      2
15      f      1
16      f      2
17      f      3
18      f      4
19      g      1
20      g      2
21      g      3
22      g      4
23      g      5
```

Comment: Honestly surprised mine performed the worst. Probably due to new DataFrame creation?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to replicate the rows and [`groupby`+`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html): to enumerate them:

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Times'])]
   .assign(Times=lambda d: d.groupby('String').cumcount().add(1))
 )
```

Output:

```
  String  Times
0      a      1
0      a      2
1      b      1
1      b      2
1      b      3
2      c      1
2      c      2
2      c      3
2      c      4
2      c      5
3      d      1
...
```

###### comparison of all answers (7k rows):

```
@mozway
11.2 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

@Onyambu
16 ms ± 685 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

@ifly6
27.3 ms ± 2.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

@ddejohn
28.5 ms ± 4.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

On 700k rows: `1s, 1.43s, 2.34s, 2.94s` in the same order

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.explode`. Make this work by converting your repetitions to list:

```
s = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
t = [2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Then,

```
times = [list(range(i + 1)) for i in t]
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': s, 'times': times}).explode('times')
```

> ```
> >>> df.head(10)
>   string times
> 0      a     0
> 0      a     1
> 0      a     2
> 1      b     0
> 1      b     1
> 1      b     2
> 1      b     3
> 2      c     0
> 2      c     1
> 2      c     2
> ```

If you don't want the index repeated like that, `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` (if in place, otherwise, reassign). If you want 1-indexing rather than 0-indexing, for `list(range(i + 1))` substitute `list(range(1, i + 2))`. Alternatively, just add one to the `times` column at the end. The `times` column doesn't really matter for `df.explode`, it explodes based on repetitions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
ss1=df.String.mul(df.Times).map(list).explode("")
ss2=ss1.groupby(ss1).cumcount().add(1)
pd.DataFrame(dict(String=ss1,Times=ss2))
```

Output:

```
   String  Times
0       a      1
1       a      2
2       b      1
3       b      2
4       b      3
5       c      1
6       c      2
7       c      3
8       c      4
9       c      5
10      d      1
11      d      2
12      d      3
13      e      1
14      e      2
15      f      1
16      f      2
17      f      3
18      f      4
19      g      1
20      g      2
21      g      3
22      g      4
23      g      5
```